# Running the R console from Sublime Text 2

Tags: r, sublimetext2

I am quite new with Sublime Text 2. I would like to write my script in ST2 and run/send it to the R console. I don't want to use SublimeREPL (most of the forums deal with this) because I want to have my R console open on the side.
I tried to install "R Tools" and the installation of this package seems to work. However, when I open my script.r file and try to run it, nothing happens. I also tried to specify the path to go to R in TOols>Build systems> new build systems... withou being successful.
Can someone give me a trick to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way is to install the `Enhanced-R` package via the Package Manager in Sublime:

1. Install the Package Control [here](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2)
2. Access the Package Manager within Sublime (on Windows: `Ctrl+Shift+P`)
3. Type **Install Package** and then **Enhanced-R**
4. Send the highlighted code to R console (on Windows: `Ctr+Enter`)

You can see the Enhanced-R package description and relevant key bindings [here](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Enhanced-R)

Comment: It seems that Enhanced-R is deprecated... the new thing is R-Box (https://github.com/randy3k/R-Box)

Comment: @intrixius Is there a way to combine this tool with https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL, so you woulda been able to send to an R running `inside` sublime2

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this post because I had a similar problem using Sublime and R. Maybe this helps someone who wants to have a similar setup. Hopefully there will be more and more R users considering Sublime. I figured out the following solution using the Sublime build system in an external xterm terminal (for Linux, but it should be very similar to a setup on Win/Mac systems):
[Sublime Text 3 build system: keep console running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310202/sublime-text-3-build-system-keep-console-running/23312269#23312269)